# Use different Authorization for one specific endpoint, .net core

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have enabled authentitaction for my Web API using bearer scheme with Identity Server 4.

In ConfigureServices i have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = identitySetttings.Authority;
                options.Audience = identitySetttings.ApiScope;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
```

and in Configure i have:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Now i'd like to exclude one specific endpoint to be **not** authenticated this way - but i don't want it to be [AllowAnonymous]. I would like to restrict requests to this endpoint for specific IP addresses and add custom claim for authenticated requests. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to remove `app.UseAuthentication();` cause this will always invoke the default authentication scheme `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` in your case. Then you could make a specific authorization policy dependent on a specific authentication scheme. It could look like this:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, Auth1>("Auth1", _ => { })
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, Auth2>("Auth2", _ => { });

services.AddAuthorization(c =>
{
    c.AddPolicy("Auth1Policy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("Auth1");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });

    c.AddPolicy("Auth2Policy", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("Auth2");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

Now annotating the controller with a policy name will invoke only an authentication scheme for that policy. Below's the way you choose the authorization policy on your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "Auth1Policy")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
```

However, restricting specific IP addresses will be easier to achieve if you take that endpoint out of this service and place it in a different API in a more secure networking environment since the public should not access it.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your suggestion, but i didn't wanted to add [Authorize] attribute for every already existing controller.
I simply added new scheme for IPAuthentication:

```
.AddScheme<IPOnlyAuthenticationOptions, IPOnlyAuthenticationHandler>("IPOnly", op => { });
```

and then in AuthenticationHandler:

```
public class IPOnlyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions { }

public class IPOnlyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<IPOnlyAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPAddress> validIPs= new[]
    {
       "xxx"
    }.Select(o => IPAddress.Parse(o));

    public IPOnlyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<IPOnlyAuthenticationOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        var identity = GetIdentityFromIPAddress(ipAddress);
        if (identity != null)
        {
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), this.Scheme.Name);
            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail($"Request not authenticated for ip address: {ipAddress}"));
    }


    private ClaimsIdentity GetIdentityFromIPAddress(IPAddress ipAddress)
    {
        if (smsApiIPs.Contains(ipAddress))
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id of my integration user") };
            return new ClaimsIdentity(claims, nameof(IPOnlyAuthenticationHandler));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

finally i can use it in my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "IPOnly")]
    [Route("type/sms/changeStatus")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(Bar model)
```