# Certificate authentication for API access alonside OpenID authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing a small application in ASP.Net8 where I use AAD authentication so that I can easily manage access through AAD groups:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Role_AdminPrivilege_Read", p => { p.RequireClaim("roles","AzureGroup_AdminPrivilege_Read"); });
});
```

This works fine, Controller can only be accessed by user with a specific policy through AAD groups. However, I also have to create an access to the API for the system account where I must use certificates because in Azure systems cannot be granted permissions like in on-premise AD.

The point is, I don't know how to start because when I add (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0):

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate();
```

my first authentication is not working anymore, but what I want to accomplish is that /api uses certificates, any other routing uses the openID one.

Yesterday I spent some hours googeling but could not find a good example, or maybe my keywords are wrong.

Can someone help me and lead me to the right direction? I think a workaround would be just creating a new application only for the API, but this sound not very clever.

Edit:
As written in the comments, adding:

p.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

solved the policies issue, but by adding a certificate authentication I cannot get a separation between openId and certificate:

```
// Sign-in users with the Microsoft identity platform
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CertificateValidationService>();

// Certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
        {
            options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
            options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                {
                    var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CertificateValidationService>();
                    if (validationService!= null && validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Success");
                        context.Success();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("invalid cert");
                        context.Fail("invalid cert");
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
    });
```

I use the two authentications. When I do that, openID and all my controller are working, except the API one. When I than add:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>( options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
        {
            options.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
            options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
        });
    });
```

The API part with a certificate works, but not the rest anymore. Is there any way I can say when the route is /api use the certificate way, if not, use non certificate way?

Edit 2:
I think the solution is to change ClientCertificateMode to:

```
ClientCertificateMode.DelayCertificate
```

Edit 3:
But then the signin button for MicrosoftIdentity is not working anymore

Edit4:
Had to modify the MS authentication:

```
builder.Services
    //.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097022/use-different-authorization-for-one-specific-endpoint-net-core maybe?

Comment: `CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` is just a name.  If you replace it with something like `"APICert"`.  You can use different names and then annotate your endpoints with `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "APICert")]` to use multiple schemes in the same application.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I think this just pushed a bit in the right direction. I have to add to my non API policies: p.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
After that at least I can use my site again and now can go further with the API

Comment: Could you kindly check [the sample code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7F9LpJ), and tell me the test result.